# Retry mongoDB query in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to configure MongoDB writes in order to retry multiple times.

According to documentation, I can achieve that by changing RetryMode in MongoDB write queries to RetryContext, in order to retry the query until context.Context.Deadline exceeds

https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver#Operation

My query code is

`MongoRepository.collection.insertOne(ctx, query)`

How can I use the `operation` and MongoRepository.collection.insertOne together to set RetryMode to RetryContext

Comment: I'm not sure this is supported. Quoting from the page you linked: _"There is only one mode that enables retry: Write."_ So I think query operations cannot be set to automatically retried. Usually there's no need for that. Write a helper / wrapper function that executes a `Find` and retries in case of error if you need it.